# prototypes for 'static' functions

Tags: c, standards

I'm not quite sure if it is really necessary to have prototypes for static functions in C. As long as I'm not exporting such functions (i.e. they don't have external linkage), what other benefit can this give?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

E.g. if you need to ensure that a function has a certain type, it can be useful.

Consider this:

```
// Define how the functions should be defined.
typedef void * jobfunc(void *);

// Use case
void addjob(jobfunc *);

// Ensure they have the right type. Without this, you only get a warning
// for addjob(job2) (see below) - with it, you get an error for the mismatch.
static jobfunc job1;
static jobfunc job2;

// Define one job
static void * job1(void * arg) {
    return NULL;
}

// Define another job - accidentally wrong.
static void * job2(int accidentally_wrong) {
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I think using typedef as some sort of function template is rather obscure practice, it will most likely just confuse the reader. For example it took me a while to interpret what your code actually does. My immediate but incorrect reaction to the code was "aha - function pointers".

Comment: @Lundin You are right as far as it is unusual. But it does its job. Maybe the `void *` return type has added confusion - as an example, I should have taken a different type. However, I don't understand why this is so unusual - it is great to ensure the right type and, apart from readability and confusion due to unknownness, I cannot see a disadvantage.

Answer (score 9):

To cite some authority, MISRA-C:2004 rule 8.1 enforces prototypes for functions with external linkage, but also mentions internal linkage:

> "The provision of a prototype for a function with internal linkage is
>   good programming practice."

I take it this is good practice because it makes your coding style between interal/external linkage functions consistent. And as others have mentioned in their answers, it is convenient as well.

Comment: This is one the few MISRA rules I agree. I always put (at top of the source file) the `static` function declarations of all the `static` functions that are defined in a source file. This is a good documentation of the code and of the internal API.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use them before the implementaion, you should write a prototype.

Usually, you can change the order of the functions, but what if you have 2 static functions, that call each other?

Comment: @Mark: E.g., the compiler needs to know what the `foo` function's signature is prior to parsing a call to the `foo` function, in order to ensure that the call to `foo` pushes the correct parameters and such.

Comment: asaelr: could you elaborate on your comment? What do you mean by 'using before the implementation' ?

Comment: like ouah wrote, I mean that you can write a caller function above of the callee function.

Answer (score 4):

A declaration without a definition of a `static` function (this is the same for an `extern` function) let you call the function before the function is defined. In C, an identifier for a function has to be declared before it can be used :

```
static void foo(void);

void bar(void)
{
    foo();
}

static void foo(void)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to everybody for comprehensive answers!

Answer (score 3):

One (minor) convenience is that it would allow you to place the functions anywhere you like in the file. For example, if you would like to place your utility functions at the end of the file, you must declare them.

A case where you must declare your functions is when you have two mutually recursive functions, as the one placed first in the file has not yet seen the other function.

Answer (score 1):

If you won't declare the function prototype the code below will be valid .

```
static int bar()
{

};

int foo()
{
   bar("asdf" );
};
```

And this kind of hidden errors may be dangerous. Checking section "2 7 .2.2 Function argument type checking" in again might be useful Principles and Practice Using C++ [Bjarne Stroustrup] .

Comment: With no prototype, this example compiles with a warning. But, if you add the prototype for `bar`, it is an error and won't compile (clang 6.0 on OpenBSD).